# Token is not a valid binary operation in preprocessor subexpression

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, cocoapods

I'm trying to build a react-native IOS app. I got it all working on Android but now I wanna test on IOS. When I try to build the project in xcode. I get the following error at 2 lines:

Line 7 in AppDelegate.m `Token is not a valid binary operator in a preprocessor subexpression`

Line 30 in AppDelegate.m `Token is nog a valig binary operator in a preprocessor subexpressio`

*My question is: How do I solve this error?*

**Contents of my AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#if def FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>

static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
  FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
  SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
  [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
  [client start];
}
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
#if def FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"Copaan"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

**Information**

React-native version: 0.36.4

React version: 16.13.1

**Things I have tried**

- I have deleted the ios folder and installed copied a new one from a new react-nativev app with the same name as my project.
- I have tried upgrading with `react-native upgrade`

Comment: What is the swift tag for?

Comment: Not sure, stackoverflow recommended it and I thought maybe this is related to swift? But I'm assuming it's not because of your question.

Comment: There's no Swift code in your question, only Objective-C. Why is the C++ tag used as well, there doesn't seem to be any C++ code involved either.

Comment: Same answer as before, I did remove the tags that aren't related.

Comment: Something is wrong with your `FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED` preprocessor expression. You need to show us the definition of `FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED`. It's possible you didn't set it to `0` or `1` but some other expression, which cannot be parsed.

Comment: Okay, where can I find the definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `#ifdef` or `#if defined` not `#if def`.

`#if` is also a valid preprocessor directive which tests for a preprocessor expression being non-zero, so there is an attempt to parse the expression `def FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED` and that produces the error.

The `#ifdef` directive takes a single preprocessor token, `FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED` in this case, and checks whether there is any defintion, with or without an associated value, for it.

There is also a `defined` preprocessor operator which can be used in the expression of an `#if` to test for a token being defined. So your expression could be written:

```
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
```

or

```
#if defined(FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED)
```

or

```
#if defined FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
```

The first is probably more common in human-written code, with the `defined` operator tending only to be used as part of a larger preproccesor expression.

HTH